# How to parse a hour format in c?

Tags: c, string, charts, format

i need to parse a char[] with this format "00:00:00" to 000000 in C, what is the best way to do this?

Ive tried to use strok but it doesnt work.
Thanks

Comment: Please show the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried and explain what is wrong.

Comment: Post the code "tried to use strok".

Comment: And then explain what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Best way is to use the [strptime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) library function. If you have constraints on what functions you're allowed to use, add them to your question.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
char* time = "00:00:00";
unsigned int h, m, s, result;

sscanf(time, "%02u:%02u:%02u", &h, &m, &s);
result = (h * 10000) + (m *100) + (s);

printf("%u", result);
```